# Check if email exists or not with python 3

Tags: python-3.x, email, dns

I have to check if the email exists or not ... I checked the validation by regex .. etc but tired trying to check the MX for the domain 
After searching I found validate_email and pyDNS 
but I'm using python 3 so I installed py3Dns but really don't know how to use
the documentation said

```
validate_email('asdasd@dasd.com', check_mx=True)
```

but it returns TimeoutError .. even I checked with a valid email and exists :)

I tried `email_validator` at this [repo](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) and didn't return me the expected result

I tried too `DNS`

```
import DNS
DNS.DiscoverNameServers()
DNS.dnslookup('google.com', 'A')
```

it returned me a list of ips ... is that enough to know if email exists or not.

Any Advice? Thanks